# How do I open a folder using a bash script running terminal

Tags: 16.04, bash, permissions

I am trying to open a specific folder that is in a script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Download youtube videos
    xterm -e /home/pst007x/Downloads/ youtube-dl https://youtu.be/-pjc1sWw6Dw
```

What is happening the terminal is opening, but I am getting permission denied.

Perhaps a stupid question, but how do I run a script to open a terminal in a specific folder?

I have permission to access this folder.

Thanks

EDIT:

This worked thanks:

```
xterm -e 'cd /home/pst007x/Downloads/ && youtube-dl https://youtu.be/-pjc1sWw6Dw'
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to "open a specific folder that is in a script". You'd rather cd to that folder, and then run commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-e` option of `xterm`, and `cd` to go to the desired directory e.g. `cd /foo/bar/`. The tricky part is that the command will be run in a non-interactive session of your login shell, so if you want to keep a shell session open, tack the desired shell directly afterwards e.g. opening `bash` on that directory:

```
xterm -e 'cd /foo/bar/ && bash'
```

If your goal is to run an one-shot command, then just use the command directly (preferably use absolute path if unsure), no need to spawn a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your script has execution permission. You can give execution permission by following command.

```
sudo chmod +x <yourscriptname.sh>
```

You can use following command to save to your download folder.

```
youtube-dl -o /home/pst007x/Downloads/  https://youtu.be/-pjc1sWw6Dw
```